# App crashes when I load Google Map fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a bottom bar on MainActivity which I use to switch between fragments. One of these fragments is being used to load Google Maps. But for some reason, app crashes as soon as I switch to map fragment. Here's my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation1);
        bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
        case R.id.bb_menu_contact:
        fragment = new ContactFragment();
        break;
}
final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        return true;
        }
        });
        }
```

**ContactFragment.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm.R.id.map;

/**
 * Created by Fasih on 19-Apr-17.
 */

public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<Location> array_list;
    private Map<Marker, Location> mMarkerHashMap;

    public ContactFragment() {

    }
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_contact);
        setupMap();

    }
    private void setupMap() {
        mMarkerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        LocationDataSource mLocationDataSource = new LocationDataSource();
        array_list = mLocationDataSource.getList();
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        for (Location item : array_list) {
           String _title = item.getLocation_name();
            String _snippet = item.getLocation_address();
            LatLng _latLng = new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            mMarkerOptions.position(_latLng).title(_title).snippet(_snippet).flat(true);
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap=googleMap;
        for (Location item : array_list) {
            String _title = item.getLocation_name();
            String _snippet = item.getLocation_address();
            LatLng _latLng = new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            mMarkerOptions.position(_latLng).title(_title).snippet(_snippet).flat(true);
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions);
            mMarkerHashMap.put(marker, item);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(marker.getPosition())
                    .zoom(11.0f)
                    .build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            LocationDetailFragment.class);
                    LocationDetailFragment.LOCATION = mMarkerHashMap.get
                            (marker);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Location.java**

```
package com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm;

/**
 * Created by Fasih on 19-Apr-17.
 */

public class Location {
    private String location_name;
    private String location_address;
    private String location_phone;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public String getLocation_name() {
        return location_name;
    }

    public void setLocation_name(String location_name) {
        this.location_name = location_name;
    }

    public String getLocation_address() {
        return location_address;
    }

    public void setLocation_address(String location_address) {
        this.location_address = location_address;
    }

    public String getLocation_phone() {
        return location_phone;
    }

    public void setLocation_phone(String location_phone) {
        this.location_phone = location_phone;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

**LocationDataSource.java**

```
package com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by Fasih on 19-Apr-17.
 */

public class LocationDataSource {
    public ArrayList<Location> getList() {

        ArrayList<Location> array_list = new ArrayList<Location>();
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setLocation_name("City Campus");
        location.setLocation_phone("+92 21 34543280");
        location.setLocation_address("Osman & Company P.E.C.H.S., Karachi, Pakistan\n");
        location.setLatitude(24.861207);
        location.setLongitude(67.0722036);
        array_list.add(location);

    return array_list;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_contact.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm.ContactFragment">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Action bar -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout_map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And finally

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".GreetingActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_greeting"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="here_goes_the_key_that_I_have _obfuscated_on_purpose" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

KINDLY NOTE THAT THE MAP HAS TO IMPLEMENT MULTIPLE MARKERS. I might be making a small mistake, but I can't get my head around it as I haven't been able to get much sleep these days.

**Stack trace**

> ```
>                                                                              --------- beginning of crash 04-23 15:04:05.465 8212-8212/com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> ```
>
> EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm, PID: 8212
>                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d008e
>   (com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm:id/content) for fragment
>   ContactFragment{7fb058f #0 id=0x7f0d008e}
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 04-23
>   15:04:05.470 1549-1969/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force
>   finishing activity com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm/.MainActivity
>   04-23 15:04:05.557 1549-2480/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Initialized EGL, version 1.4 04-23 15:04:05.557
>   1549-2480/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 04-23
>   15:04:05.558 1296-1725/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and
>   usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 15:04:05.559
>   1549-2480/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config
>   with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without... 04-23
>   15:04:05.559 1549-2480/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior
>   0 04-23 15:04:05.562 1296-1725/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc:
>   format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23
>   15:04:05.571 1296-1725/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and
>   usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 15:04:05.979
>   1549-1579/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for
>   ActivityRecord{706171f u0
>   com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm/.MainActivity t118 f} 04-23
>   15:04:05.998 1296-1347/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and
>   usage 0x333 imply creation of host color buffer
>
> ```
>                                              [ 04-23 15:04:06.004  1549: 1579 D/         ]
>                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8d36fb80, tid 1579 04-23
> ```
>
> 15:04:06.019 1296-1296/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1296:
>   eglCreateSyncKHR(1669): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE) 04-23
>   15:04:06.060 1549-1579/system_process D/gralloc_ranchu:
>   gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling
>   thread) 04-23 15:04:06.061 1296-1725/? D/gralloc_ranchu:
>   gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color
>   buffer 04-23 15:04:06.090 1296-1725/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc:
>   format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23
>   15:04:06.105 1296-1725/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and
>   usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 15:04:06.233
>   2123-2123/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/OptInState:
>   There is a new client and it does not support opt-in. Dropping
>   request. 04-23 15:04:06.239 1296-1347/? D/gralloc_ranchu:
>   gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color
>   buffer 04-23 15:04:06.254 1296-1347/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc:
>   format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23
>   15:04:06.261 2123-2123/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtV3s.png)].
>   04-23 15:04:06.261
>   2123-2123/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder 04-23 15:04:06.272
>   1296-1347/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900
>   imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 15:04:06.279
>   2123-8520/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection. 04-23 15:04:06.288
>   2123-2179/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@67c3040 04-23
>   15:04:06.297 1993-2242/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp:
>   No location to return for getLastLocation() 04-23 15:04:06.299
>   1302-1342/? W/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() failed opening
>   input: samplingRate 16000, format 1, channelMask 10 04-23 15:04:06.299
>   2123-2179/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 641, record
>   source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
>   04-23 15:04:06.299
>   2123-2179/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization
>   check failed with status -22. 04-23 15:04:06.299
>   2123-2179/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native
>   AudioRecord object. 04-23 15:04:06.299
>   2123-2179/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@67c3040 04-23
>   15:04:06.300 2123-2179/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded 04-23
>   15:04:06.300 2123-2123/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady 04-23 15:04:06.320
>   2123-2179/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@67c3040 04-23
>   15:04:06.321 2123-8520/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished 04-23 15:04:06.322
>   2123-8520/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading
>   from input stream 04-23 15:04:06.322
>   2123-2374/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection. 04-23
>   15:04:06.323 2123-8520/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
>                                                                                                 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from
>   input stream
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
>                                                                                                  Caused by:
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error
>   code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
>                                                                                                     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
>   04-23 15:04:06.323
>   2123-8520/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/AudioController: internalShutdown

[image][image]

Comment: post a lot of code...but missed the essential one!..post the logcat error of the crash...

Comment: Just posted stack trace.

Comment: @LunarWatcher. Pictures are there just to help imagine and run cold test. Not relevant indeed.

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onCreateView()` in your Fragment and inflate your layout there.

Remove `onCreate()` implementation.. also change your `setupMap()` to use `getChildFragmentManager()`

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{


SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ArrayList<Location> array_list;
private Map<Marker, Location> mMarkerHashMap;
View rootView;

public ContactFragment() {

}

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
    setupMap();
    return rootView;
}

private void setupMap() {
    mMarkerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    LocationDataSource mLocationDataSource = new LocationDataSource();
    array_list = mLocationDataSource.getList();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    for (Location item : array_list) {
       String _title = item.getLocation_name();
        String _snippet = item.getLocation_address();
        LatLng _latLng = new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        mMarkerOptions.position(_latLng).title(_title).snippet(_snippet).flat(true);
    }
}
```

Also your `<meta-data>` tag should be inside of `<application/>` tag

Comment: Won't it cause a 'statement unreachable?' Previously, I was doing something like that.

Comment: Oh. No, it won't. Got it. Let me try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571881/switch-between-fragments-with-mapview

Answer (score 2):

Instance of getSupportFragmentManager() use getChildFragmentManager()  .

You have to change below line coding.

```
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Though you were the first one to point in right direction, Rafsanahmed007 was more precise. Thank you.