# Switch between fragments with MapView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a main_activity with a bottom bar. I am using this bottom bar to navigate between fragments. However, there's this one fragment that's not directly navigatable via that bottom bar. It must be accessible from the fragment with MapView and upon `onInfoWindowClick`. However, the app crashes whenever I consume the infoWindow. Here's my code

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tesla);
        mMap=googleMap;
        for (Location item : array_list) {
            String _title = item.getLocation_name();
            String _snippet = item.getLocation_address();
            LatLng _latLng = new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude());
            final MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(icon);
            mMarkerOptions.position(_latLng).title(_title).snippet(_snippet).flat(true);
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions);
            mMarkerHashMap.put(marker, item);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(marker.getPosition())
                    .zoom(12.0f)
                    .build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    LocationDetailFragment detailedlocation = new LocationDetailFragment();

                    detailedlocation.LOCATION = mMarkerHashMap.get(marker);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content, detailedlocation);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });
        }
```

> ```
>                                                                              --------- beginning of crash 04-23 19:41:11.380 2573-2573/com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> ```
>
> EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm, PID: 2573
>                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm.LocationDetailFragment.onCreateView(LocationDetailFragment.java:35)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 04-23
>   19:41:11.383 1564-1957/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force
>   finishing activity com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm/.MainActivity
>   04-23 19:41:11.414 1296-1653/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density
>   must be defined as a build property
>
> ```
>                                              [ 04-23 19:41:11.456  1564: 3367 D/         ]
>                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x87cb5680, tid 3367 04-23
> ```
>
> 19:41:11.457 1296-1653/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and
>   usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 19:41:11.457
>   1564-3367/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version
>   1.4 04-23 19:41:11.458 1564-3367/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 04-23 19:41:11.458 1564-3367/system_process
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without... 04-23 19:41:11.458
>   1564-3367/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0 04-23
>   19:41:11.462 1296-1653/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and
>   usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 19:41:11.476
>   1296-1653/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900
>   imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 19:41:11.892
>   1564-1591/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for
>   ActivityRecord{34a233 u0
>   com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm/.MainActivity t141 f} 04-23
>   19:41:11.921 1296-1962/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and
>   usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 19:41:11.940
>   1296-1962/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900
>   imply creation of host color buffer 04-23 19:41:11.951 1296-1962/?
>   D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply
>   creation of host color buffer 04-23 19:41:11.968 1296-1426/?
>   D/PermissionCache: checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for
>   uid=1000 => granted (252 us) 04-23 19:41:12.025 1296-1426/?
>   D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x333 imply
>   creation of host color buffer
>   Blockquote

```
package com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class LocationDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public static Location LOCATION;
    TextView _campusName;
    TextView _campusAddress;


    public LocationDetailFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_detail, container, false);

        _campusName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.campus_name);
        _campusAddress = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.campus_address);

        _campusName.setText(LOCATION.getLocation_name());
        _campusAddress.setText(LOCATION.getLocation_address());
        return view;

    }
    public void onClick_call(View view) {
        dialPhoneNumber(LOCATION.getLocation_phone());
    }
    public void dialPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

> 04-23 19:58:11.735 6856-6856/com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm, PID: 6856
>                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   **com.teslaqubitsins.fasih.teslahcm.LocationDetailFragment.onCreateView(LocationDetailFragment.java:35)**
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 04-23
>   19:58:12.507 2006-2282/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp:
>   No location to return for getLastLocation() 04-23 19:58:42.534
>   2134-2214/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   W/GmsLocationProvider: Error removing location updates: 16

Comment: post the crash log....

Comment: @rafsanahmad007. Check please.

Comment: post your `LocationDetailFragment` also ..cause the exception focus on that class

Comment: @rafsanahmad007. Please check now.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007. Also note that I am calling `onInfoWindowClick` from a class `ContactFragment` that's being extended by `Fragment`. I am trying to call `LocationDetailFragment` from `ContactFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 _campusName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.campus_name);
 _campusAddress = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.campus_address);
```

use the fragment's inflated view to get the ID's:

```
 _campusName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.campus_name);
 _campusAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.campus_address);
```

the exception occurs as your `getView()` returns null, it is not associated with the fragment's `View`. In `fragment` You have to always use the inflated view's reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574251/cant-start-a-call-from-within-a-fragment-class

Comment: Please have a look here too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585343/does-scrollview-work-in-fragments